How do I download all of the files on the Inspect Element network tab?
(there are 12000 files, all blob files (originally png i think) but that is okay) I would like them to download as if i had clicked "save image as" on every single one of them. (clicking the "save image as" saves it as something like "COM_01057BA1-F54A-4A9E-A555-1DA956C5C535 File (.com_01057ba1-f54a-4a9e-a555-1da956c5c535)" which is fine with me as i can convert them all later)
I tried using gchrome/msedge extensions but they saved the blob: files as .txt files with the blob: files' url thing instead.

Does the blob URL on that text open?

What do you mean by open?

Can you paste it in the address bar and it comes up?

It says file not found, but I can copy it as datauri
